# How to install Dell firmware update from Ubuntu Software app

Tags: updates, dell, xps, firmware

I have an update from Dell for my laptop (see screenshot below). When I click on "Restart & install", it does shutdown/reboot the computer, but the update is never applied.

[image: Ubuntu Software app updates]

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative command that I can run to apply the update?

**edit**-> here's a screen shot of information provided after clicking on the update:

[image: details]

Comment: What kind of update is it? Does clicking on it gives some kind of description?

Comment: I added an image of the details that popup upon clicking on the update. It isn't much info.

Comment: You need to install the update and then shutdown fully and then turn on the computer.  It's a BIOS firmware update that won't apply on a warm reboot, it needs to happen from a typically cold boot on some XPS/precision models

Comment: @ThomasWard how do I install the update?

Comment: @matt it happens automatically when the BIOS/firmware picks up the update,  Are you saying that it doesn't?  Did you get an "Install" option you could click and then showed you that red notice?

Comment: @ThomasWard . That is the answer.  Shutdown the laptop and turn it back on.  The update is only applied during a cold boot up not a warm boot.

Comment: @matt Confirm that works, and I'll add it as an answer.  If it doesn't work something else is going on.

Comment: @ThomasWard.  Cold boot is the answer.  On a cold boot, there were some screen updates about updating various bios devices.   After they were applied, the updates screen in the Ubuntu software is reporting all software is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *special* class of updates called "Firmware Updates" which affect your BIOS and system firmware on the system board.  These typically come from Dell and hardware manufacturers, and typically firmware updates like this do not get applied during a warm boot (aka a "reboot").

You typically need to do what is called a 'cold boot' - a full shutdown and then turn on the computer again from that cold 'powered off' state - for the firmware to pick up on the fimrware update needing installed.  During that process it'll see it has a pending firmware update and apply it.

(This is the case on my XPS 15 9570 and likely other XPS/Precision models)